# multidimensional array using foreach

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I'm writing a code for looping out data from an multi dimensional array.
While looping I got confused while getting the details from an array. I have tried several ways for getting but in vain.

Now what I want is to get the values from the **key 4** provided in the array.

```
Array
(
    [match1] => Array
    (
            [4] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Sanjay
                            [1] => Delhi
                            [2] => 23
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Ram
                            [1] => Mumbai
                            [2] => 26
                        )
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Sanjay
                            [1] => Delhi
                            [2] => 23
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Ram
                            [1] => Mumbai
                            [2] => 26
                        )
                )
    )
)
```

Thanks

Comment: With your question, I believe you just need `$arr["match1"][4]`, right?

Comment: Adding to Praveen Kumar may  be you want `$arr["match1"][4][0]`  or  `$arr["match1"][4][1]`

Answer (score 1):

In order to access the multi dimensional array you need to access via `foreach()` or directly by using the keys that you have in the `print_r()` function.

Hence as per your Example you can directly access the variable the you need using the

- first array variable along with the key that the first array has.

Consider this array and you need to fetch the first value you can process like this.

`print_r($var);` resulting in this

```
Array
(
    [match1] => Array
    (
            [4] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Sanjay
                            [1] => Delhi
                            [2] => 23
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Ram
                            [1] => Mumbai
                            [2] => 26
                        )
                )

    )
)
```

You can retrieve the variable in two methods as follows

**Method One:**

As the variable that contains the array is `$var` hence you need to access like this.

In order to fetch the value that the key has you can have `$var['match1'][4]`  and you can apply foreach over to the variable and get the value that it has.

```
foreach($var['match1'][4] as $inner_value)
{
// Do what ever stuff you need
}
```

**Method Two:**

- **Getting key value 0** - `0` in the array that it has you can code as -  `$var['match1'][4][0]`
- **Getting key value 1** - `1` in the array that it has you can code as -  `$var['match1'][4][1]`

You can get as much value inside the array as you can with the help of the above two points

**Output for both it will be the same as follows**

```
Sanjay Delhi 23
Ram Mumbai 26
```

Answer (score 0):

It's really very simple. Let's assume the name of your main array is `$mainarray`. So here is how you can get the array of **key 4**.

```
$key4array=$mainarray['match1'][4];
foreach($key4array as $arrayele) {
   echo $arrayele[0]." ".$arrayele[1]." ".$arrayele[2]."<br>";
}
```

Output will be,

```
Sanjay Delhi 23
Ram Mumbai 26
```

Access the first level array by `match1` key and then `4` as index to get the second level array.